# Building a Rails custom forum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, oop

I have a Comment and Reply scaffolds.

The table "comments" plays role of the forum's 'posts' table. It is difficult to refactor it so I left it with this name.

schema.rb

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text "content"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.boolean "anonymous"
 t.integer "user_id"
 t.string "title"
end

create_table "replies", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.boolean "anonymous"
 t.text "text"
 t.integer "user_id"
 t.integer "post_id"
 t.string "title"
end
```

Models

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, optional: true
   validates_presence_of :content, :title
   has_many :replies, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Reply < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment, optional: true
  validates_presence_of :text, :title
end
```

This is how I create a reply:

```
def create
  #@comment = Comment.find(:post_id)
  #@reply = @comment.replies.create(:user_id, :anonymous, :text, :post_id, :title).permit(:reply)

  @reply = Reply.new(reply_params)
  @reply.user_id = current_user.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @reply.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reply }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

You can probably see that the database relations are not properly connected.

To display a post and its replies I do have to go over all of the replies in the forum and display the ones with instance variable post_id == current_post.id.

I think that there is a way to link replies directly to its post. You can see my attempt (commented lines it in the create function) but it is not working and I think there might be several things to modify starting from schema.rb. Could you advice me how to approach the refactoring.

- when I uncomment `@comment = Comment.find(:post_id)` I get an error:

> Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=post_id

And I'm not sure what to do with the next line:

```
#@reply = @comment.replies.create(:user_id, :anonymous, :text, :post_id, :title).permit(:reply)
```

I don't really have @comment.replies table or instance in my schema.rb. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a `comment_id` column to your replies, or specify the `foreign_key` in the model, i.e.

```
class Reply < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment, foreign_key: 'post_id'
  ...
end
```

(I've removed the `optional: true` as a reply needs a comment right? You've got `dependent: destroy` switched on so I'd guess so :) )

You'll then need to attach the comment to the reply somewhere - either a hidden field with the id in the form view (be sure to permit all the params), or in a similar manner to which you're assigning a reply to a user: `@reply.comment = a_comment_instance`.

Hope that helps?

---

Edit: re the error you've mentioned, `@comment = Comment.find(:post_id)` is looking for a Comment with an id of (literally) `:post_id` - do you mean `@comment = Comment.find(params[:post_id])`?

Comment: I think you are getting the things the other way around. Comment is actually the Post or the Thread. And Reply are the actual comments inside the thread(post) @SRack

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm following - have you tried out the code above? If the foreign key doesn't correspond to the model name (you've `post_id` in the `replies` table), you need to specify it. If you want to switch the assignment above around for readability's sake, you could do `a_comment_instance.replies << @reply`. (Also, if you're running into confusion at this stage, I'd _definitely_ say it's worth the time to rename the data - it'll save you (and others) pain in the long run!)

Comment: I've added the foreign key code and when I include  '@reply = @comment.replies.create(:user_id, :anonymous, :text, :post_id, :title).permit(:reply)' I have an error 
wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 0..1)

Comment: I think it's probably worth having a look at some tutorials on how to form controllers, strong params and associations. The code in your comment is  a little way from working - you'd usually use something like `@reply = @comment.replies.create(reply_params)`. The best guide, IMO is [Michael Hartl's](https://www.railstutorial.org/). I hope this doesn't come across badly - I've been there myself and received the same instruction (albeit pretty bluntly :) ). Hope that helps!